# Is it true that there exists any Borel set with positive measure in $\mathbb{R}$ is equal to some interval almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel set with positive Lebesgue measure. Is it true that there exists an interval $I$ such that $A = I$ almost everywhere? For example, $A = [0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is equal to $[0,1]$ almost everywhere. I'd like to know if this observation generalizes.

Comment: What about $A = [0, 1] \cup [4, 5]$?

Comment: Ah right I should have said a union of (countable) nondegenerate intervals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider a [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) $X$: this has positive measure but is nowhere dense and so for any nondegenerate interval $I$ we have $I\setminus X$ has positive measure.

Not only is such an $X$ Borel, it's even *closed*!